# VSCode Flutter Debug and Execution given a no-sound-null-safety

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Until yesterday everything worked just fine. But for publishing reasons I needed to update my flutter SDK and gradle version, and after that my VsCode debug simply stopped working. It keeps giving me the `Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".` error.

`Flutter doctor:`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Linux Mint 21.1 5.15.0-76-generic, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Here's my vsCode.json configs:

[image]
[image]
[image]

After I reopen the VsCode it also gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: What is your Flutter version?

Comment: @Albert221 Sorry I forgot to add versions, just a sec

Comment: Don't know exectly what happened, but after a reboot it worked just fine... Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Flutter 3.10, which uses Dart 3:

> Dart 3—planned for a mid-2023 release—requires sound null safety. It will prevent code from running without null safety, or with unsound null safety. All existing code must be migrated to sound null safety to be compatible with Dart 3. To learn more, see the Dart 3 sound null safety tracking issue.

[— Unsound null safety | Dart](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety)

So you have two options really:

- migrate back to Dart 2, that is Flutter 3.7 or earlier,
- migrate your code to sound null safety.

Comment: This is not possible. I created this project this year, its been about 4 months. My environment sdk is '>=2.19.1 <3.0.0' from day zero... I made with null safety from the beggining

Comment: So why do you need the `--no-sound-null-safety` then?

Comment: VsCode debugger was asking me to add that... But after a reboot it worked just fine. Thank for your time. I'll close this question